# Parsing this JSON format - keys listed once, multiple values

Tags: python, json

I'll preface by saying that I've only been learning Python and looking at APIs and JSON for about a month, but that I did also search first and didn't immediately find a question similar to this.

I am trying to call an API (do an API call?) that supposedly returns JSON, but the response looks like this:

```
{
  "result":[
    [
      "Facility Type",
      "Facility Name",
      "Facility Address",
      "ZIP",
      "Phone",
      "Facility Amenities / Notes",
      "Website",
      "Latitude",
      "Longitude"
      ],
      [
        "Parks",
        "Boysen Park",
        "951 S. State College Blvd.",
        "92806",
        "714-765-5191",
        "Baseball, softball, volleyball, football, soccer, tennis",
        "http://www.anaheim.net/comm_svc/parks/parkDetail.asp?dir=park_boysen",
        "33.82610235",
        "-117.889968814"
      ],
      [
        "Parks",
        "Citrus Park",
        "104 Atchison St.",
        "92805",
        "714-765-5191",
        "Volleyball, basketball",
        "http://www.anaheim.net/comm_svc/parks/parkDetail.asp?dir=park_citrus",
        "33.836792198",
        "-117.906545597"
      ]
}
```

This doesn't look like a JSON response I've come across before. I'm used to responses that look like this (using the above as an example):

```
{
  "result": [
    [
      "Facility Type":"Parks",
      "Facility Name":"Boysen Park",
      "ZIP":"92806"
    ]
  ]
}
```

which would allow me to do something like...

```
name1 = response['result']['Facility Name']
```

...to have name1 equal "Boysen Park".

How would I do this for the above response?

(This is where I am getting the API/JSON information from: http://anaheim.opendata.junar.com/dataviews/89522/city-parks/ )

Here's the API request, in case anyone else is interested:

```
http://anaheim.cloudapi.junar.com/api/v2/datastreams/CITY-PARKS-58641/data.ajson/?auth_key=[AUTH_KEY]&limit=5&
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When APIs respond like this it normally means the format is pretty much fixed and you could possibly assume accessing by index would not break in the future. If the format changes they would normally create a new endpoint. (At least in a sane world).

I would either just access by index and assume the value is always the same for the endpoint, or create a dict for each entry using the headers.

```
for i, entry in enumerate(data['result']):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    # Do something with the entry
    print(entry)
    # You could make a dict
    d = dict(zip(data['result'][0], entry))
    print(d)
```

Would print the following for the first entry:

```
['Parks', 'Boysen Park', '951 S. State College Blvd.', '92806', 
 '714-765-5191', 'Baseball, softball, volleyball, football, soccer, tennis', 
 'http://www.anaheim.net/comm_svc/parks/parkDetail.asp?dir=park_boysen',
'33.82610235', '-117.889968814']

{'Facility Type': 'Parks', 
 'Facility Name': 'Boysen Park', 
 'Facility Address': '951 S. State College Blvd.', 
 'ZIP': '92806', 
 'Phone': '714-765-5191', 
 'Facility Amenities / Notes': 'Baseball, softball, volleyball, football, soccer, tennis', 
 'Website': 'http://www.anaheim.net/comm_svc/parks/parkDetail.asp?dir=park_boysen', 
 'Latitude': '33.82610235', 
 'Longitude': '-117.889968814'
}
```

If you access using dict keys (directly) you would at least know if something changes in the future. I also always add simple sanity checks such as ... are all the arrays actually of size 9?

Doing the key access from the code above would be:

```
d['Phone']
d['Website']
```

Again, you could also just assume what the fields contain in the code:

```
entry[4]
entry[6]
```

.. is the same as the first example

Comment: Awesome. Makes perfect sense. I guess I was thrown off by the unexpected format, instead of looking at it a little more closely and realizing that I could just treat the results as lists, since that's what they are. Clearly I have much more to learn them what I have in a month so far. Thanks again for your help and if I had a higher rep, I'd upvote you.